# Kibana/Elasticsearch/logstash install issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an issue installing Kibana/elasticsearch/logstash.
I followed the instructions for the download and the install of each.  From the Admin CMD line, I ran the elasticsearch.bat for elasticsearch. The script ran, but just hung and never fully completed. However, when testing on my localhost 9200, it showed ES installed correctly. I did the same with Kibana and had the same result. The script never fully completed, however, I was able to open the web app on port 5601. I also completed the install for logstash – the script never fully completed. When I manually exited each script by exiting the cmd window, I lost connection to the localhost. "This site can't be reached."

Has anyone had this issue or know what might be happening here?

Comment: you'd need to share the command you are running and it's output plesae

Comment: Thank you for responding to my post.

1. I downloaded and unzipped Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash.
2. I opened a CMD prompt as Administrator and moved to the Elasticsearch/bin directory
C:\Elastic\elasticsearch-7.15.2\bin
3. I run elasticsearch.bat from that directory.
4. The install script runs until it gets to the point:   "successfully reloaded changed geoip database file [C:\Users\ADMINI~2.SLA\AppData\Local\Temp\2\elasticsearch\geoip-databases\-_Vg0yHxTmCUgOfbz-Lv1Q\GeoLite2-City.mmdb]."  I can verify that the script ran successfully by checking the port at localhost:9200.